# What's the difference between xpub and bpub?

Tags: cryptography, bip32-hd-wallets, xpub

I've seen extended public keys such as the one below

```
xpub661MyMwAqRbcFLCsW67CH9AgprkK2MbeLbmdMiBRWb1Wamm6GjGhTFQChvPmwQGQh78MMd8Eu7CLJ7FEuwhsomD66XC74VnfgHdEx1NFSKL
```

But now I've seen a bpub

```
bpubgqxJY83YqBS1rgM392MqkPnaa7P8yBEkZ7pZksTUHjRxQRn8RzuL8ST1NYhAqgbM7f3SDzTTJifL1WuCYvVxHinLuhF4kFdnBNN34N4Y2et
```

What's the difference?

Comment: I don't recall this being defined in any (common) spec. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: `bpub` is probably the prefix for extended public keys for an altcoin.

Comment: @RaghavSood I found it while trying to answer a question about pywallet - and thus extended keys.

https://github.com/Ballanxe/pegaso/blob/5e0cbf8439c175becd80beb92e9e1fb075b65a47/src/.env

Comment: @AndrewChow can you elaborate? What are prefixes? When do they apply? Why are they the same for some altcoins but not others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bpub` [appears to be](https://github.com/blockcypher/blockcypher-python/blob/master/blockcypher/constants.py#L89) the extended private key prefix for the Blockcypher testnet.

Bitcoin addresses and private keys usually have a prefix to help differentiate the network/type of key.

The original `xpub` notation comes from BIP32, meaning `extended public key`. This expanded into `ypub` with BIP49, and finally `zpub` with BIP49+ (used in BIP84).

Various coins can define their own prefix by simply altering the bytes. Litecoin, for instance, often uses `Ltub`.

It works the same way as changing the address prefix, except you change four bytes, instead of one.